# How to save if default data is installed on an iOS app sharing data with iCloud

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui, cloudkit

I'm developing an iOS-App with SwiftUI right now. Upon first run of the app I am saving default data to CoreData which is then synced with CloudKit in order to make it available on all devices using the same Apple Id.

I'd like to prevent the app from saving the default data multiple times (e.g. when the data is already saved in CloudKit and the other devices doesn't need to save it again because it can pull it from iCloud). Doing this I already tried different approaches, which doesn't bring me to the aim:

1. I tried to save one specific flat to CoreData and sync it to iCloud which was a Boolean called "isAlreadyInstalled". When starting the app I was getting it from CoreData and skipping the installation of the default data when necessary. The problem with this approach is that I cannot wait for CloudKit to sync with my CoreData database which means the "isAlreadyInstalled" value is always false. I also tried it with a sleep of a couple of seconds on every start, but when the CoreData and CloudKit database becomes larger the sleeping time would be very inconvenient for the user upon every startup of the app.
2. I tried to use NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore which seemed as the perfect solution in the first place. But after uninstalling and reinstalling my app and clearing the CloudKit database the NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore is not cleared, which means the default data will not be installed. I already looked for clearing the NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore when the app will be uninstalled but that's not possible.

I'm kind of confused right now because I can't find any approach making the installation dependent on the iCloud sync or waiting for the iCloud sync to happen.

Just for reference: I do not load the persistentStoreContainer in my AppDelegate because I wrote my own CoreDataHelper-Class in which I'm doing all the CoreData magic. I cannot imagine that there is no solution for my problem as it seems really common to install default data and share it between different iCloud devices.

I would really appreciate any help and can of course share some code if necessary!

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue right now..My iOS and mac app both create sample data. However, when syncing I do not want duplicated values. I haven't figured a solution yet. I thought of assigning a unique key which is always the same, and then iCloud shouldn't duplicate these values, instead merge them.

Comment: Thanks for joining @davidev. Unfortunately I wasn't able to fix it by now. Would appreciate if you could share your solution after finding one.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore